# In a set of dates and numbers select the latest next immediate date to the date where the number equals to

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the below table for each account is there a way to pull the latest next immediate date to the date where the Inventory = 5?

| Account | Date | Inventory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2019-04-01 | 5 |
| 123 | 2019-05-01 | 6 |
| 123 | 2019-07-01 | 9 |
| 123 | 2019-08-01 | 5 |
| 123 | 2019-09-01 | 8 |
| 123 | 2019-10-01 | 9 |
| 54321 | 2018-01-01 | 5 |
| 54321 | 2018-02-01 | 7 |
| 54321 | 2018-03-01 | 5 |
| 54321 | 2018-04-01 | 9 |
| 54321 | 2018-05-01 | 8 |

Expected outcome

| Account | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2019-09-01 |
| 54321 | 2018-04-01 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the next row in the table where `id = 5`, then I would expect `lead()` to be used:

```
select account, max(next_date)
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by account order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where inventory = 5
group by account;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=176e6f0d321a906535bae3105ec4a964) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an identity column or you can achieve the same by **ROW_NUMBER()** as well.
Use below query:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY
    ,Account INT
    ,[Date] DATE
    ,Inventory INT
    )

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES (123,'2019-04-01',5)
    ,(123,'2019-05-01',6)
    ,(123,'2019-07-01',9)
    ,(123,'2019-08-01',5)
    ,(123,'2019-09-01',8)
    ,(123,'2019-10-01',9)
    ,(54321,'2018-01-01',5)
    ,(54321,'2018-02-01',7)
    ,(54321,'2018-03-01',5)
    ,(54321,'2018-04-01',9)
    ,(54321,'2018-05-01',8)

SELECT Account
    ,[Date]
FROM @T
WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT MAX(ID) + 1
        FROM @T
        WHERE Inventory = 5
        GROUP BY Account
        )
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: @Max . . . It is quite surprising that you accepted this answer.  First, it is using a column that is not in your question.  More importantly, it is using `identity` to assign the value, and then assuming that "next" means `id + 1`.  That is just wrong on multiple fronts, including no guarantee that the ids have no gaps and no guarantee that the next id is even for the same account.  That is happens to work on the sample data does not mean the query is a correct solution.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, you're right your solution makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 2 account
FROM table
WHERE inventory = 5
ORDER BY date DESC
```

[Sql Server Tutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/)